# Getting graphic/movie clip x,y position from within another movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, graphic

This should be fairly simple I'd think, I'm just not that familiar with actionscript haha.

I have a game where I have the background moving behind a character that stays in one position on screen. I'm relatively new to actionscript 3 but I'm wanting to have text boxes pop up whenever the player presses a key over certain objects passing in the background.

So, basically the background itself is a movie clip, and I have other graphics and movie clips within the background mc.

I was thinking of getting the player.x and y position and then "comparing" that position (>= and <=, etc.) with the graphic/movie clip in the background. But I just don't know how to obtain the x  and y coordinate of the graphics/movie clips in the background mc.

Comment: Sounds like you want to compare how close different display objects that are in different coordinate spaces are to each other. Have a look at .localToGlobal, this method converts coordinates to the global space, and by converting objects in the background and the player coords to global you can compare them to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to target your movie clips in the background by getting their coordinates, then removing their parent's position (the background container).

Something like :

var finalXPosition:int = targetMovieClip.x - backgroundContainer.x;

var finalYPosition:int = targetMovieClip.y - backgroundContainer.y;

By substracting the target movieclip parent's position to its position, you gain the final position in the parent's scope coordinates.
It should work for you as soon as your character and your background container are situated at the same level of the display list.

Here is a quick diagram of what I try to explain (please forgive my inaptitude to draw nice and explicit drawings ^^)
[image]

Usually, when I stumble upon such a case, I try to make a quick and even dirty drawing, starting with what I want, then breaking down every useful data I have to achieve that result, you should keep that method in mind and try it the next time ! :-)

Comment: Ah such an in depth explanation with diagrams! Hmm... I'm afraid I still can't quite grasp it though, still learning the ins and outs of actionscript so that may be why. Thank you very much for the suggestion though! I just need a little more explanation on how to actually get the targetMovieClip's coordinates? Like what exactly do I need to do to get my target MovieClip's position in actionscript 3? I think after I know that I should be able to take care of everything else myself. Thanks again for being so helpful!

Comment: (to clarify I only need to know about getting the target mc's position from within the background mc), as my background actually starts at the X = 0 coordinate! How handy!

Comment: Ah, that's what I was "afraid" of :-) No problem, I'll try to explain : in Flash, every element (movieclip) can be accessed via its "name".x or .y . If you know its parent (here, the background for example), you can access your movieclip by using myBackground.myMovieClip : each of these (background, target movieclip) have properties like x, y, width, height... So basically,  to have your target movieclip's position, you'll need : your background position (I suppose you know it if you make it move) and the target position inside that background (using the dot notation I've mentionned above).

Comment: Yeah right, comments crossing ^^ tell me if you can use the dot notation I've told you about in the previous comment : if you're not familiar with Flash & Actionscript, you need to know that nested movieclips (movieclips inside movieclips) have different coordinates origin : each time you "enter" an new nesting level, the coordinates origin is resetted to its container origin. An exemple : a movieclip at 10/20 inside an another movieclip positionned at 50/100 will be on the screen at 60/120, but its relative position will be 10/20 until you hange it. Am I clear enough ? (I'm afraid not ^^)

Comment: Ah haha, yeah, I'll have to look into it all and do some testing to figure it out myself completely. But I really appreciate the help! I may not be going about creating the game the "best" way but so far it's come along well. Just certain things trip me up a bit, it'll take some time but I'll get it! I'll post back here again after I really review what you've said and either figure it out or still need help.

Comment: Okay I went through and I understand what you were trying to get me to do. I'm running into issues where it's not actually subtracting the x position from the background and object though. I have a variable that looks like this, var finalXpos:int = Mybackground.Myobject.x - Mybackground.x; but it doesn't actually subtract the two. I used trace to see what was going on and the var finalXpos doesn't ever change from 305, the background.x is changing though. I tried something out and put var backpos = Mybackground.x and it never updated its position even though the background is obviously moving.

Comment: Ah I get the error #1009 when I trace(Mybackground.Mymovieclip.x).

Comment: Maybe the MyMovieClip isn't part of the MyBackground movieclip ?... That would be the first thing that come to my mind when seing that error. Or maybe you've mispellen the names you're using ...? It often happens :-)

Comment: But I've got it working now! After tweaking it for a while I got it setup so that the object's original position is being tracked along with how the scene moves. It may have been misspelling... not quite sure. But thanks for all the help @bertrand.riche !